# Merge from different branch into different folder

Tags: git, merge

we recently moved from SVN to GIT. Since the project is quite big with SVN we used to branch folders rather than the whole project. The current structure is now:

```
trunk
   core
     web
   db
branches
   MainDevBranch A (branched from trunck/core/web)
   OtherBranch(branched from MainDevBranch)
```

Now merging OtherBranch>MainDev branch is working fine but I couldn't get to merge changes trunk>MainDevBranch as if I try all files results as added!

Is there a way out of this? I couldn't find a git flow to help me.

Answer (score 0):

After consulting with a few Git expert looks like it is not possible to do what I'm trying to.

The only option is to merge manually, possibly using a tool (i.e. http://www.araxis.com/merge/index.en)